# How to control output by if statement

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, console.writeline

```
if (vm.Name != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("VM name is \"{0}\" and ID is \"{1}\". State is: \"{2}\". Location: \"{3}\" and the Instance Type is \"{4}\". Key is \"{5}\".",
        vm.Name, vm.InstanceId, vm.State, vm.Region, vm.InstanceType, vm.KeyName);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("VM ID is \"{0}\". State is: \"{1}\". Location: \"{2}\" and the Instance Type is \"{3}\". Key is \"{4}\".",
        vm.InstanceId, vm.State, vm.Region, vm.InstanceType, vm.KeyName);
}
```

I'm trying to do as little copy-pasting here as possible. My question's how to shrink this code so that simply apply **if-statement** only for the first bit of information `vm.Name` and not the whole output line?

Comment: I think you can build the first sentence separately from the second sentence here.

Comment: Have you looked into string interpolation and conditional logic? http://thebillwagner.com/Blog/Item/2015-07-05-StringInterpolationandtheConditionalOperators

Comment: Sentence refactorisation. Totaly worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an expression. Something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "VM {0}ID is \"{1}\". State is: \"{2}\". Location: \"{3}\" and the Instance Type is \"{4}\". Key is \"{5}\".",
    vm.Name != null ? $"name is \"{vm.Name}\" and " : string.Empty, vm.InstanceId,
    vm.State, vm.Region, vm.InstanceType, vm.KeyName);
```

Comment: I like this solution - short and easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like,

```
    //Here you will check condition and format first few words of sentences
    var str = vm.Name != null ? $"name is {vm.Name} and " : string.Empty;
    //if name is not null then add it to zeroth position otherwise add empty string
    Console.WriteLine($"VM {str}ID is {vm.InstanceId}. State is: {vm.State}. Location: {vm.Region} and the Instance Type is {vm.InstanceType}. Key is {vm.KeyName}.");
```

Bonus: [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X8euz9)

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstPart = string.Empty;
if (vm.Name != null)
{
    firstPart = $"VM name is {vm.Name}";
}
else
{
    firstPart = $"VM ID is {vm.InstanceId}";            
}

Console.WriteLine($"{firstPart}. State is: {vm.State}. Location: {vm.Region} and the Instance Type is { vm.InstanceType}. Key is {vm.KeyName}.");
```

You can change name of `firstPart` variable. Nothing better haven't came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Do the part that you know it always has and replace it...? It's not the nicest, but should work.

```
var output = string.Format("VM ID is \"{0}\". State is: \"{1}\". Location: \"{2}\" and the Instance Type is \"{3}\". Key is \"{4}\".",
             vm.InstanceId, vm.State, vm.Region, vm.InstanceType, vm.KeyName);

if (vm.Name != null) {
    output.Replace("VM ", $"VM name is "\"{vm.Name}\" ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare the `Name` attribut as nullable

and do somthing like this :

```
string val;
            if (vm.Name != null)
            {
                val = "VM name is \"{0}\" and";
            }
            else
            {
                val = "VM";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(
                  val + " ID is \"{1}\". State is: \"{2}\". Location: \"{3}\" and the Instance Type is \"{4}\". Key is \"{5}\".",
                  vm.Name, vm.InstanceId,
                  vm.State, vm.Region, vm.InstanceType, vm.KeyName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this. Nice, easy and readable.

```
string VmName = "";

if(vm.Name != null)
  VmName = "name is \"" + vm.Name + "\" and"; 

Console.WriteLine("VM " + VmName + " ID is \"{0}\". State is: \"{1}\". Location: \"{2}\" and the Instance Type is \"{3}\". Key is \"{4}\".",
                 vm.InstanceId, vm.State, vm.Region, vm.InstanceType, vm.KeyName);
```